# Preventing spawned processes from being killed when application shuts down

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a ASP.NET core application that spawns long-running processes using System.Diagnostics.Process.Start. I want these processes to keep running even if the web application is shut down. However, for reasons unknown, the processes are killed when the application is stopped (using Ctrl+C from the console).

I set a breakpoint after the return of `IHost.Run()`, and that confirmed that the processes have already been killed when that method returns. This does not happen with a regular C# console application. It seems like the ASP.NET Core is somehow registering the processes I spawn and shutting them down as part of the application shutdown procedure. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Based on your description and scenario, I think you can use the BackgroundService class to run a background task independently of the web requests. This is more aligned with the lifecycle of an ASP.NET Core application and may allow your long-running processes to survive the application shutdown.
Implement a class that inherits from BackgroundService and starts your long-running processes in the ExecuteAsync method.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron: As far as I can tell from the documentation, background services implemented using the BackgroundService class are also shut down (via the StopAsync method) when the application shuts down. I really want to create a process whose lifetime is independent of the application lifetime.

Comment: It would great if you could share the code snippet in a way so that it can be reproduced accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I had to set ProcessStartInfo.CreateNoWindow to `true` to "detach" the spawned process.